# outputstream writer java for integers

Tags: java, csv

I am quite new in java, I need to save xml to csv using java, but problem is I cannot use CSVWriter because in xml there are also UTF8 encoded data.

Therefore I found out it is possible to use outputstreamwriter, which can be encoded in UTF8.

For string everything is ok, but for integer I cannot get correct number.

Sample code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.*; 

public class UTF8WriterDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Writer out = null;
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("c://java2//file.csv"), "windows-1250"));


//for (int i=0; i<4; i++ ) {



            String text = "This tečt will be added to File !!";
            int hu = 4;


            out.write('\ufeff');

            out.write(text+ '\n');   
            out.write(hu+ '\n');  
//}

            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I get picture instead of a number.
I suppose it's because:

> An OutputStreamWriter is a bridge from character streams to byte streams: Characters written to it are encoded into bytes using a specified charset. The charset that it uses may be specified by name or may be given explicitly, or the platform's default charset may be accepted.

And that's why it's not displayed correctly.

Therefore I would like to ask, is there any option for integers to be displayed using outputstreamwriter?

Or if not, how can I convert xml data into csv using java for UTF8 encoded characters?

Thank you

Comment: Try `out.write(hu + "\n");`

Comment: Why are you writing a BOM to a `windows-1250` encoded text file?

Comment: because otherwise csv is not displaying string correctly. In .txt it`s ok, but for csv I had to put BOM.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a difference between using double quotes and single quotes.

- `"foo"` is a String.
- `'f'` is a char (or Character)
- `'foo'` will throw an Exception, because you can only have 1 character in a char.

`'\n'` is also 1 character, specifically the newline character. Adding a number and a character will use the number as an ASCII value and use the corresponding character, then combine both characters into a String (or array of characters, ie. char[]).

Using double quotes should fix your issue.

Comment: it fixed int problem, but now String is not displayed correctly:"?This teèt will be added to File !!"

Comment: @bennes How are you verifying the contents of the file?  It appears you are using a text viewer/editor which assumes the file is ISO-8859-1 (or windows-1252).  The byte 0xe8 represents č in windows-1250, but è in windows-1252 and ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Opening the csv file. The whole code output must be in csv. 
Only out of curiosity, how do you check encoding bytes to certain symbol? Is there some common database for encodings and its bytes translations please?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;

public class UTF8WriterDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Writer out = null;
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new      FileOutputStream("file.csv"), "windows-1250"));

            //for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                String text = "This text will be added to File !!";
                int hu = 4;
                String text2 = new String("" + hu);

                out.write('\ufeff');

                out.write(text + '\n');
                out.write(text2 + '\n');
        //  }

            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("The process is completed.");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: not working:(
output in csv: "?This teèt will be added to File !!"

Comment: Please post a screenshot if possible

Comment: I don’t see an issue with your output.

Comment: č is changed to é.
but meanwhile I solved, so no more problem. Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

actually I need to rewrite this construction:

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new 

FileWriter("C:\\java\\test\\EEexample3.csv");
        CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(fileWriter);
        csvWriter.writeNext(new String[] {
            ..
..
..
..
        }
```

..code.. code..

```
String homeCurrencyPriceString = iit.getHomeCurrency().getPrice()!=null?iit.getHomeCurrency().getPrice().toString():"";
                                String headerDateString = invoiceHeaderType.getDateTax()!=null?invoiceHeaderType.getDateTax().toString():"";
                                String invoiceTypeString = invoiceHeaderType.getInvoiceType()!=null?invoiceHeaderType.getInvoiceType().value():"";
                                String headeraccountno= invoiceHeaderType.getAccount().getAccountNo()!=null?invoiceHeaderType.getAccount().getAccountNo().toString():"";
                                String headertext = invoiceHeaderType.getText()!=null?invoiceHeaderType.getText():"";
                                String invoiceitemtext= iit.getText()!=null?iit.getText():"";
                                String headericdph = invoiceHeaderType.getPartnerIdentity().getAddress().getIcDph()!=null?invoiceHeaderType.getPartnerIdentity().getAddress().getIcDph():"";
                                String symVar = invoiceHeaderType.getSymVar()!=null?invoiceHeaderType.getSymVar():"";

                                csvWriter.writeNext(new String[] {
                            invoiceHeaderType.getPartnerIdentity().getAddress().getIco(), headericdph, invoiceHeaderType.getPartnerIdentity().getAddress().getCompany(),symVar, invoiceHeaderType.getId().toString(), iit.getId().toString(), homeCurrencyPriceString, detailcentreString,headercentreString, headerDateString, invoiceTypeString,headeraccountno, headertext,invoiceitemtext
                                });
```

where objects are filled by xml

to outputstreamwriter construction.
So first I am trying outputstream as simple code, to be sure it`s working , next when it works, I wanted to rewrite the whole code.

Using CSVwriter everything works smoothly, just now there were added texts encoded in UTF8/windows1250 :( Therefore I need to fix the construction of code.

Even number objects like price are converted using .toString(), so maybe it works without int.

I hope writer of outputstreamwriter is able to do what is necessary.
I am going to try.